# Drupal Add Javascript type=text/javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add javascript to my page and use type="text/javascript" however when I include the following it just encloses it in script tags. How can I fix this? Also, how can I add the type="text/javascript to external files (see the second example)

```
drupal_add_js("$(document).ready(function() {
    // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
    jQuery.ias({
        container : '#itemcontainer',
        item: '.dealstable',
        pagination: '.nav',
        next: '.nav a',
    });
    });",'inline');
```

Here is the second example:

```
drupal_add_js('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js','external');
```

UPDATE:
As suggested by the comments I tried the following:

```
$js = "(function($) {
    jQuery.ias({
        container : '#itemcontainer',
        item: '.dealstable',
        pagination: '.nav',
        next: '.nav a',
    });
    };
})
(jQuery)";
drupal_add_js($js, array('type' => 'inline','scope'=>'footer'));
```

But that resulted in the following HTML:

```
<script>(function($) {
    jQuery.ias({
        container : '#itemcontainer',
        item: '.dealstable',
        pagination: '.nav',
        next: '.nav a',
    });
    };
})
(jQuery)</script>
```

Comment: text/javascript is the default type, though it appears Drupal core adds that by default anyway in [drupal_get_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_js/7) '#attributes' => array(
      'type' => 'text/javascript',
    ),

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
$js = "(function($) {

    };
})
(jQuery)";
drupal_add_js($js, array('type' => 'inline','scope'=>'footer'));
```

OR

```
drupal_add_js("(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mobile-navigation').click(function(){

     });
    });
})
(jQuery)","inline");
```

OR

```
drupal_add_js('sites/all/themes/dawn/js/skrollr.js', array('scope'=>'footer'));
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'module name') . '/js/name.js');
```

Comment: Please format your code as code. Also, a bit of description why it works and code by OP does not would be helpful.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I have updated my original edit to show the result.